# Can we call custom label in application event while setting the event attribute if yes then what will be the syntax. see my docNotSignedAtr

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, aura-attribute

```
  function(response){
             //Bug-8928---Prod issue resolution start-Amit>08-02-2022
            if(response == null){
                console.log('null response from requestSignedDocument '+response);
            /*var docNeedSignAgain = $A.get("$Label.c.CLV1_DocNotSignedAfterOneShot");
            component.set("v.hasToBeSignDocAgain", docNeedSignAgain);
            */
                
              var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:docNotSigned");
              appEvent.setParams({
             "docNotSignedAtr" : $A.get("$Label.c.CLV1_DocNotSignedAfterOneShot") });
              appEvent.fire();
                
                
                var signedDocumentLink = $A.get("$Label.c.CLV1_ApplicantspaceURL")
                
                var Url= $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
                Url.setParams({
                    "url": signedDocumentLink
                });
                 Url.fire();                
            }**strong text**
```

Comment: That looks like it should work. What's the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: i put a debug after my parameter setup but i am not getting any logs in console.
console.log('docNotSignedAtr :' +docNotSignedAtr);
i think my event is not firing. I am firing my event in helper file after getting some response. Can we fire the event in helper file ?